# Rotting orange problem - cannot get expected value

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

So the problem is given a basket of **n** rows and **m** columns, find the minimum number of days required to rot all oranges, knowing that there is always at least 1 rotten orange in the basket, and their positions are given as input nested list **positions**.

(EDIT: apologies, forgot to add the rotting rule, but basically adjacent oranges to a rotten orange should rot the next day e.g. if orange at [1,1] is rotten today, oranges at [0,1], [2,1], [1,0], [1,2] should rot the next day)

Just cannot get the expected output from the input below, and I cannot see where my code went wrong. Really starting to feel like the expected output given is somehow problematic. Would be great to have some advices.

**Input**: n = 3, m = 7, positions = [[2,4]]

**Expected output**: 4

**Actual output**: 6

```
def rottingOrange(n,m,positions):
    #Idea: Find cells that have not rotten
    #If either cell next to it have rotten, it will also rot
    #If there is no more cells that have not rot, stops
    
    def isValid(i,j,positions):
        #Determine if an orange position is adjacent to a rotten orange
        if [i-1,j] in positions or [i+1,j] in positions or [i,j-1] in positions or [i,j+1] in positions:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def rot(grid,positions):
        #Find all oranges that should rot for the current day
        temp = []
        for i,j in grid:
            if isValid(i,j,positions): 
                temp = temp + [[i,j]]
        if len(temp) < 1:
            return "cannot rot"
        else:
            grid_new = [x for x in grid if x not in temp]
            positions_new = positions + temp
            return grid_new, positions_new

    def rotting(grid, positions):
        #find the number of days taken to rot all oranges
        if len(grid) <= 0 or rot(grid, positions) == "cannot rot":
            return 0
        else:
            grid_new = rot(grid,positions)[0]
            positions_new = rot(grid,positions)[1]
            if len(grid_new) == len(grid):
                return rotting(grid_new,positions_new)
            else:
                return 1 + rotting(grid_new,positions_new)

    def grid_creation(n,m,positions):
        #create grid of size n x m, and remove all oranges that have rotten
        grid = []
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                grid.append([i,j])
        for x in positions:
            if x in grid:
                grid.remove(x)
        return grid

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        grid = grid_creation(n,m,positions)
        return rotting(grid,positions)
```

Comment: I dont think this can be solved efficiently with recursion, try suing BFS instead where all rotten cells will be starting ones with distance of 0, then the maximum distance in BFS will be the answer. Recursion is essentially just DFS which does not find shortest path

Comment: Can you link to the original challenge? Usually the input to this problem is different, and I think you might have missed a thing in the input. For instance, the problem with the same name on LeetCode and on GeeksForGeeks is different from what you tell us here.

Comment: "find the minimum number of days required to rot all oranges, knowing that there is always at least 1 rotten orange in the basket" What is the rule that says which oranges become rotten on what day?

Comment: Apologies, added the rule for rotting oranges, basically adjacent oranges to rotten ones should rot

Answer (score 1):

Your program is based on index. If Position is [[2,4]], then index position is [[1, 3]]. You will get expected output as 4 if you will provide index position as input or you can covert position to index position inside your program.

**Also find a different approach to the problem.**

```
def get_neb_pos_list(r_lim, c_lim, r_pos):
        neb_list = [(r_pos[0] + 1, r_pos[1]) if r_pos[0] + 1 < r_lim else (r_pos[0], r_pos[1])] + \
                   [(r_pos[0] - 1, r_pos[1]) if r_pos[0] - 1 >= 0 else (r_pos[0], r_pos[1])] + \
                   [(r_pos[0], r_pos[1] + 1) if r_pos[1] + 1 < c_lim else (r_pos[0], r_pos[1])] + \
                   [(r_pos[0], r_pos[1] - 1) if r_pos[1] - 1 >= 0 else (r_pos[0], r_pos[1])]
   return neb_list


def get_min_days_to_rot(n_rows, n_cols, r_pos):
    oranges = [(i, j) for i in range(n_rows) for j in range(n_cols)]
    if r_pos[0] not in oranges:
        return "Invalid Position"
    if n_rows <= 0 or n_cols <= 0:
        return "Invalid number of rows or columns"
    if len(oranges) == 1:
        return 0
    rot_oranges = list(r_pos)
    n_days = 0
    while len(rot_oranges) < n_rows * n_cols:
        for pos in r_pos:
            rot_list = get_neb_pos_list(n_rows, n_cols, pos)
            rot_oranges.extend(rot_list)
        rot_oranges = list(set(rot_oranges))
        r_pos = list(rot_oranges)
        n_days += 1
    return n_days


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 3
    m = 7
    pos = [(1,3)]
    n_days = get_min_days_to_rot(n, m, pos)
    print(n_days)
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dWTasnWs-M&ab_channel=yilmazbingol

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.directions=[
                    [-1, 0], 
                    [0, 1], 
                    [1, 0], 
                    [0, -1],
                    ]
    def orangesRotting(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        fresh_oranges=0
        queue=deque()
        ROWS,COLS=len(grid),len(grid[0])
        # get the initial state of the grid
        for i in range(ROWS):
            for j in range(COLS):
                if grid[i][j]==1:
                    fresh_oranges+=1
                if grid[i][j]==2:
                    queue.append((i,j))
        minutes=0
        current_batch_size=len(queue)
        # process all the bad oranges
        while queue:
            # 1 minute passes when i process each batch
            if current_batch_size==0:
                minutes+=1
                current_batch_size=len(queue)
            current_orange=queue.popleft()
            current_row=current_orange[0]
            current_col=current_orange[1]
            current_batch_size-=1
            # check the neighbors of current_orange
            for direction in self.directions:
                next_row=current_row+direction[0]
                next_col=current_col+direction[1]
                if next_row<0 or next_row==ROWS or next_col<0 or next_col==COLS:
                    continue
                # if next orange is fresh, convert to a bad orange
                if grid[next_row][next_col]==1:
                    grid[next_row][next_col]=2
                    fresh_oranges-=1
                    queue.append((next_row,next_col))
        if fresh_oranges!=0:
            return -1
        return minutes
```